# Most wins by a second place team in NBA history

Tags: basketball, nba

What's the most wins an NBA team finishing 2nd in wins/loss in a conference has achieved?

This came to mind because the Dodgers recently set a record in the MLB for the most wins without winning a division title. And given that the Warriors and Suns are currently neck-and-neck in the West at 24-5, I was just curious what the record was for 2nd best record in a conference for the NBA.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the Spurs in 2016, who went [67-15](https://www.espn.com/nba/standings/_/season/2016)... finishing 6 games behind the record setting Warriors (73-9).  That is [tied for 7th all-time by winning percentage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NBA_teams_by_single_season_win_percentage) for *any* team.